# D3.js data() method with json data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a json string that has 5 objects. I tried to draw five `rect`s(same with the number of objects in json data) however more `rect`s are rendered than i expected.
What is the problem?

```
//json: [{"name":"136","count":1},{"name":"142","count":1},{"name":"147","count":1},{"name":"150","count":3},{"name":"152","count":5}]

var svg = d3.select(".wrapper")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);

svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(json)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("y", function (d, i) { return 100+i*24; })
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("width", 500)
.attr("height", 20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating the JSON as a string and not parsing it to an object.  You should be doing

```
JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

Compare this:

```js
var json = '[{"name":"136","count":1},{"name":"142","count":1},{"name":"147","count":1},{"name":"150","count":3},{"name":"152","count":5}]';

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(json)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 100 + i * 24;
  })
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

To this:

```js
var json = JSON.parse('[{"name":"136","count":1},{"name":"142","count":1},{"name":"147","count":1},{"name":"150","count":3},{"name":"152","count":5}]');

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(json)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return 100 + i * 24;
  })
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```